# How do I initialize a struct field which is a mutable reference to an Option?

Tags: syntax, reference, rust, mutable

How do I initialize a struct field which is a mutable reference to an `Option<T>`? Here is my struct:

```
pub struct Cmd<'a> {
    pub exec: String,
    pub args: &'a mut Option<Vec<String>>,
}
```

I tried to initialize this struct like this:

```
let cmd = Cmd {
    exec: String::from("whoami"),
    args: None,
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:15
  |
9 |         args: None,
  |               ^^^^ expected mutable reference, found enum `std::option::Option`
  |
  = note: expected type `&mut std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>`
             found type `std::option::Option<_>`
  = help: try with `&mut None`
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: If you don't specify, we assume that you are using the current stable version of Rust. If you are not, it is **strongly** encouraged that you upgrade. Error messages improve all the time.

Comment: I didn't realize that it wasn't brew that maintains the rust version. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to provide a mutable reference. Like this:

```
let cmd = Cmd {
    exec: String::from("whoami"),
    args: &mut None,
};
```

Comment: Now I'm getting confused: what is the lifetime of a temporary? It seems here that the temporary `None` gets an extended lifetime (at least greater than `cmd`), when I thought temporaries would not outlive the evaluation of the expression that created them.

Comment: @MatthieuM The lifetime will last for the containing block scope. If it was passed as a function argument instead then it would just be the immediately surrounding parentheses. See: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f72221dc92e4a1b08029f7bdac294f9b&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: I could not find a definitive answer, and google brings up a bunch of RFCs/blog articles/PRs but it's not clear whether they're up to date, so I've created a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760946/when-is-a-temporary-destructed in which I invite you to share your knowledge since you seem to know the rules :)