# When is a temporary destructed?

Tags: rust

Up until now, I assumed that a temporary was destructed at the end of the evaluation of the statement that had spawned it.

However, it appears that there is an exception made when using a temporary to initialize the field of a `struct`.

PeterHall helpfully provided a simple [code sample illustrating the difference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f72221dc92e4a1b08029f7bdac294f9b&version=stable&backtrace=0) in a comment to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748749/147192), which I've <strike>simplified</strike> complicated a bit:

```
struct Wrapper<'a> {
    cmd: &'a Cmd<'a>,
}

struct Cmd<'a> {
    args: &'a Option<String>,
}

impl <'a> Cmd<'a> {
    fn new(args: &'a Option<String>) -> Cmd<'a> {
        Cmd {
            args: args,
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    // OK
    let cmd = Cmd {
        args: &None,
    };

    // OK
    let cmd = Wrapper {
        cmd: &Cmd {
            args: &None,
        }
    };

    // Lifetime error
    let cmd = Some(Cmd {
        args: &None,
    });

    // Lifetime error
    let cmd = Cmd::new(&None);
}
```

So, what is the exact rule for when a temporary is destructed?

Comment: I do not know the explanation, but for sure that is not consistent.

Comment: Feels related to the "lifetime checking stops at function boundaries" aspect. The working case has a struct initializer and thus is more "transparent" to the compiler, while the failing case is a function call.

Comment: @Shepmaster: That could be something like this indeed, after all borrowing works independently for fields of a local variable, but not across function calls.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Ah... looks like enum constructors are treated like functions... (see updated tests).

Comment: @MatthieuM. because they *are* functions :-) That's why you can do things like `iterator.map(MyEnum::Alpha)`. Also your updated code doesn't have any enums...?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Well... they are many things, you cannot generally pattern match on functions, but of course you can on enumerators.

Comment: We wouldn't have to worry about this if [RFC 66](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0066-better-temporary-lifetimes.md) was implemented!

Comment: @FrancisGagné: That RFC! Felix is talking about `~[T]` which is a syntax I hadn't seen in ages!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the second failing line first:

```
let cmd = Cmd::new(&None);
```

`&None` creates a temporary with a lifetime of the single line. `Cmd::new` returns a `Cmd` that has the same lifetime. Then we have attempt to store that temporary in a variable with `let`.

The [Rust reference states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes):

> When a temporary rvalue is being created that is assigned into a let
>   declaration, however, the temporary is created with the lifetime of
>   the enclosing block instead...

It tries to increase the lifetime of the `Cmd` temporary, but that depends on the lifetime of the `&None` temporary, and since that temporary isn't actually stored in a `let` (the exception to the rule about temporaries lasting until the end of the statement), its lifetime is less than the lifetime of `cmd` and you get a lifetime error.

The direct struct statements work, because the `let` lifetime applies to the struct and its members.

The fact that it doesn't work for `Some` (an enum) seems like a bug to me (or at least a missing feature).